# Print Composer pdf export: map as raster, just text as vector

Tags: qgis, print-composer, pdf

Is it possible, to export a print composer map as PDF with all shapes as raster and just the text (embedded) as vector?

My maps use transparency and blending, so I'm forced to export them as raster. Thats okay, if the text would be vector and editable in scribus/inkscape.

Comment: Maybe this video helps you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5T03PZkJ_tQ

Answer (score 4):

Set each individual shapefile layer to render as a raster.

For each layer that you want to render as raster, go to its

> Properties>Rendering>"Force layer to render as a raster"

Then when you export a map from print composer, make sure that you *don't* check "Print as raster"

This should render each layer as a raster while leaving everything else as a vector.